# list results into none after appending in a recursive function call

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I wrote a code which on given a sum and a list of coins will return a set of coins that add up to that sum

eg.  input:
sum = 7
coins = [2,3]

```
 output:
 [3,2,2]
```

but when it was returning none
when I debugged the code I found that the result variable was computed correctly but when it appends c it turns into none

```
def coinSum(sum,coin):
    if sum == 0:
        return []
    if sum < 0:
        return None

    for c in coin:
        reminder = sum - c
        result = coinSum(reminder,coin)
        if result is not None:
            returnValue = result.append(c)
            return returnValue

    return None
```

After that, I wrote this code which gave the correct output

```
def coinSum(sum,coin):
    if sum == 0:
        return []
    if sum < 0:
        return None

    for c in coin:
        reminder = sum - c
        result = coinSum(reminder,coin)
        if result is not None:
            returnValue = result + [c]
            return returnValue

    return None
```

what is the difference here? when I check it with a simple list, the append function works properly

Comment: ``list.append`` returns ``None``.

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to assign append to a variable or something like that. Here is an example.

```
x = []
y = x.append(2)
print(y)
```

**output**

```
None
```

So in your case here is an example of using your first code.

```
def coinSum(sum,coin):
    if sum == 0:
        return []
    if sum < 0:
        return None

    for c in coin:
        reminder = sum - c
        result = coinSum(reminder,coin)
        if result is not None:
            result.append(c)
            return result

    return None
print(coinSum(9,[2,1]))
```

Notice I don't assign `result.append(c)` to a new variable.